# add new column in a dataframe depending on another dataframe's row values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to add a new column to dataframe `DF1` but the new column's value should be calculated using other columns' value present in that `DF`. Which of the other columns to be used will be given in another dataframe `DF2`.
eg. DF1

```
|protocolNo|serialNum|testMethod  |testProperty|
+----------+---------+------------+------------+       
|Product1  |  AB     |testMethod1 | TP1        |
|Product2  |  CD     |testMethod2 | TP2        |
```

DF2-

```
|action| type|               value       |        exploded |
+------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
|append|hash |        [protocolNo]       | protocolNo      |
|append|text |            _              |     _           | 
|append|hash | [serialNum,testProperty]  | serialNum       |
|append|hash | [serialNum,testProperty]  | testProperty    |
```

Now the value of **exploded** column in `DF2` will be column names of `DF1` if value of **type** column is **hash**.

`Required` - 
New column should be created in DF1. the value should be calculated like below-

`hash[protocolNo]_hash[serialNumTestProperty]` ~~~ here on place of column their corresponding row values should come.

eg. for Row1 of DF1, col value should be

```
hash[Product1]_hash[ABTP1]
```

this will result into something like this **`abc-df_egh-45e`** after hashing.

The above procedure should be followed for each and every row of DF1.

I've tried using map and withColumn function using UDF on DF1. But in UDF, outer dataframe value is not accessible(gives Null Pointer Exception], also I'm not able to give DataFrame as input to UDF.

Input DFs would be DF1 and DF2 as mentioned above.

Desired Output DF-

```
|protocolNo|serialNum|testMethod  |testProperty| newColumn      |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+       
|Product1  |  AB     |testMethod1 | TP1        | abc-df_egh-4je |
|Product2  |  CD     |testMethod2 | TP2        | dfg-df_ijk-r56 |
```

**newColumn** value is after hashing

Comment: Edit your question and add your code to see what´s happening

Comment: Can you please list the input DFs and the desired Output DF. That would be helpful.

Comment: @tamilnad posted input DFs and the output DF.

Comment: @SonaliSharma Did you check my answer?

Comment: @tamilnad yes it worked with that. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of DF2, you can translate DF2 to case class like Specifications, e.g

```
case class Spec(columnName:String,inputColumns:Seq[String],action:String,action:String,type:String*){}
```

Create instances of above class

```
val specifications = Seq(
Spec("new_col_name",Seq("serialNum","testProperty"),"hash","append")
                     )
```

Then you can process the below columns

```
 val transformed =  specifications
        .foldLeft(dtFrm)((df: DataFrame, spec: Specification) => df.transform(transformColumn(columnSpec)))

def transformColumn(spec: Spec)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = { 

 spec.type.foldLeft(df)((df: DataFrame, type : String) => {
           type match {
                  case "append" => {have a case match of the action and do that , then append with df.withColumn}

}
}
```

> Syntax may not be correct

Answer (score 0):

Since DF2 has the column names that will be used to calculate a new column from DF1, I have made this assumption that DF2 will not be a huge Dataframe.

First step would be to filter DF2 and get the column names that we want to pick from DF1.

```
val hashColumns = DF2.filter('type==="hash").select('exploded).collect
```

Now, `hashcolumns` will have the columns that we want to use to calculate hash in the `newColumn`. The `hashcolumns` is an Array of `Row`. We need this to be a `Column` that will be applied while creating the `newColumn` in DF1.

```
val newColumnHash = hashColumns.map(f=>hash(col(f.getString(0)))).reduce(concat_ws("_",_,_))
```

The above line will convert the `Row` to a `Column` with `hash` function applied to it. And we `reduce` it while concatenating `_`. Now, the task becomes simple. We just need to apply this to DF1.

```
DF1.withColumn("newColumn",newColumnHash).show(false)
```

Hope this helps!